# SSIS Script Task check if file exists: fails from SQL Job

Tags: file, ssis, task, exists

My SSIS Script Task works fine when is executed in debug mode, but when I execute package from a SQL Job, it doesn't: it doesn't find the file, even if the file exists.

The package and the file to found are on the same server; the SQL DB is on another one. I use the UNC path for finding file and I gave the right permission to the users defined on the file folder.

Comment: Do SQL Agent permissions allow access to the folder?

Comment: Does it return an error, and if so, what is the full, exact error message?

Comment: How can I verify if SQL Agent permissions allow access to the folder? Thanks